# XSLT formatting of string

Tags: xslt

I am a novice when it comes to XSLT.

I run the below select

```
<xsl:value-of select="./@name"/>
```

I get the following result

> TestSomething.Cancel(GIVEN WHEN THEN)

I want the output to say

> GIVEN WHEN THEN

instead of TestSomething.Cancel(GIVEN WHEN THEN)

Would be thankful if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ...

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(./@name,'('),')')" />
```

Comment: After posting the question I went away to work on it and it was fairly easy! Thank you for your post its what it did!#

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you could post the source XML and some information on the xslt processor you are using, but at a guess I'd say this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(./@name, '('), ')')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```